# MSIInstallProduct raises System.AccessViolationException x64 Windows OS

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I've got following problem: I've written an application in C# which uses `MSIInstallProduct`
to install a .msi file. I use following signature:

```
[DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]    
public static extern UInt32 MsiInstallProduct(string packagePath, string commandLine);
```

If I run this under a x86 Windows everything works fine. But if I run it under x64 Windows
I get following error message:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This mostly happens while MSI action `InstallFiles` or `WritingRegistryKeys`

Has someone got an idea how I can fix that?

Comment: I don't see anything in this question that explains the behavior you're seeing. If the error isn't until the MSI actions, that means the install started, so it's probably not a problem with the API signature. And there's little else to go on here.

Comment: Have you an idea how i can get further information about this issue? Propably 3rc party software?

Comment: Successively try steps that better simulate what you're doing now. For example, run the equivalent msiexec.exe command line, and see if it works. If it does, write a small C++ program that calls MsiInstallProduct similarly to your P/Invoke, and see if it works. If you're doing anything that involves, say, a C# external UI handler, double-check or remove it.

Comment: Are you executing your program with admin rights ?